# How do can I have a dropdown list(select HTML) where i want to have one of the options where i allow the user to enter a user specif entery?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, rhtml

I want to have a drop down menu where a user can select from several predefined options but i also want to give him the option of inserting a user specific value, i was thinking having one of the options as `"user specific"` which will in turn allow the user to insert a user specif entry in a text box that appears or is editable when user selects the `"user specific"` option. any one have any ideas how i can implement this is HTML and Javascript?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach an `onchange` event to the select and when he selects "Custom" or something like that, make some `input` visible below the select. This input should be initially hidden (css `display:none`). When the user selects "custom" make it `display:inline`.

Answer (score 1):

Jukka wrote an article on how to create [a combobox-like effect](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/combo.html). I've only skimmed it, but it looks accessible and his content is usually of very high quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can go about like:

```
<select id="myid" onchange="doIt(this);">
  optons...
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doIt(field) {
if (field.value === 'user specific')
{
  var tbox = document.createElement('input');
  tbox.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  document.form_name.appendChild(tbox);
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/EscRV/

html

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option>value 1</option>
   <option value="[new]">new</option>
</select>
```

js

```
// get a cross-browser function for adding events, place this in [global] or somewhere you can access it
var on = (function(){
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        return function(target, type, listener){
            target.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
        };
    }
    else {
        return function(object, sEvent, fpNotify){
            object.attachEvent("on" + sEvent, fpNotify);
        };
    }
}());

var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");    
on(mySelect, "change", function(){
    if (this.value === "[new]") {
        var newOptionName = prompt("input new option");
        if (newOptionName){
            mySelect.options[mySelect.options.length] = new Option(newOptionName);
            this.value= newOptionName;
        }
    }
}); ​
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help to solve your problem.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<select id="sbox">
<option value="1" onclick="hideUserOption();">First option</option>
<option value="2" onclick="hideUserOption();">second option</option>
<option value="3" onclick="showUserOption();">User Specific</option>
</select>
<div id="userOptions" style="display:none">
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showUserOption() {
        var userOptions = document.getElementById("userOptions");
        userOptions.style.display = "block";
    }

    function hideUserOption() {
        var userOptions = document.getElementById("userOptions");
        userOptions.style.display = "none";
    }


</script>
</body>



</html>
```